# Error when setting DGV DataSource to null - "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm sorry if this has been answered already, I have been through numerous solutions on this site with no luck. Basically, I have a DataGridView and I am assigning a DataTable to the DataSource property. The first time I assign the DataTable, I do not have an issue. However, any subsequent time after, I get "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." The solutions I have found suggest something like:

```
dgv.DataSource = null; // index out of range error here
dgv.Rows.Clear();
```

However, I STILL get the index out of range error when trying to assign null to the DataSource so it won't work. I appreciate any feedback.

Edit: I am using .NET 7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is throwing that exception?

Comment: Probably the cause of your exception is inside some event handler bind to the grid in which you don't provide safety checks on the datasource == null (or better rows.count == 0) scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error I am getting is not related to this DGV but another DGV that I had that was changing based on this one.

It seems this is the solution for resetting a DGV DataSource:

```
dgv.DataSource = null;
dgv.Columns.Clear();
dgv.Rows.Clear();
```